# How to caulcate Euler Angles [Roll Φ(Phi), Pitch θ(Theta), Yaw Ψ(Psi)] between two XYZ cartesian coordinates/points (Origin to Target)?

Tags: rotations

I have two point (Origin and Target) in 3D XYZ cartesian coordinates.
How to caulcate Euler Angles rotation [Roll Φ(Phi)/α(alpha), Pitch θ(Theta)/β(Beta), Yaw Ψ(Psi)/γ(Gamma)] between the two points, from Origin to Target?

Comment: Please use MathJax for formulas. You can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing Euler angles between two 3D points from Cartesian coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4431933/computing-euler-angles-between-two-3d-points-from-cartesian-coordinates)